# Pronunciation of הגפן when drinking alone

Tags: blessing, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, pronunciation

The blessing over wine, בורא פרי הגפן is pronounced differently between Ashkenazim and Sefardim. Ashkenazim say *hagafen*; Sfardim *hagefen*.

There [seem to be](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59806/hagefen-or-hagafen-what-is-the-reason-behind-the-enunciation-difference/59825#59825) a couple possibilities for why. According to the answer on the linked previously question, Ashkenazim changed the text to be more in line with Biblical Hebrew, where at the end of a sentence, an accented *segol* will switch to a *kamatz* (simplified), while Sfardim didn't. The other possibility, ascribed to Rabbi Ovadia Yosef, is that the amen after is part of the blessing, so הגפן isn't the last word. I infer from here that he thinks it really should be *hagafen*, but the amen changes it.

If a Sfardi, following Rabbi Yosef's opinion, is drinking alone, with no-one around to answer *amen*, how should he pronounce הגפן? The way he usually does, or change it *hagafen*?

Comment: Is there any official source for Rav Ovadia's ruling? I couldn't find it anywhere online (other than the linked answer).

Comment: also seems strange being that I saw this comment in Yalkut Yosef (at http://www.yahadoot.net/item.asp?id=1174&cid=16) : כדמוכח בברכות (מ.). וכן פסק מרן בשלחן ערוך יו"ד (סימן יט ס"ד), ואע"פ שאמן זה הוא על הברכה שעוסק בה, בכל זאת נחשב הפסק. וכמ"ש כיו"ב בשו"ת פנים מאירות חלק ב (סימן ה), שהמברך בורא פרי הגפן על היין, ולפני שיטעם ענה אמן אחר ברכת בפה"ג של חבירו, הוי הפסק, וברכה לבטלה בירך, וחייב לחזור ולברך כיון שהפסיק באמן, וכדמוכח ממ"ש מרן הבית יוסף או"ח (סימן נט), וראה בחזון עובדיה על הלכות חנוכה however, he could still hold its a hefsek since its his friend's bracha... hmm.

Comment: (That quote is also found in Yabia Omer 6:OC:5)

Comment: I once read that Moroccans say “Hagafen” when alone, although I haven’t verified it.

Answer (score 1):

In the קיצור ש''ע ילקוט יוסף in [סימן רד - דיני הברכות על יתר המאכלים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_16.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L2) he does not bring a reason nor does he differentiate between being alone or with others (who could answer Amen).

He says that the popular custom is to always use a double-Segol - הַגֶּפֶן

> כה כבר פשט המנהג אצלינו לברך בברכה ראשונה על היין **''בורא פרי הַגֶּפֶן '' בסגו''ל**. [ילקוט יוסף, תפלה כרך ב', מהדורת תשס''ד, עמוד תקצז. קול תורה תמוז תשס''ג עמוד מט, חשון תשס''ד עמוד כ'].‏